# Need to optimize SQL Query - Taking lot a of time for execution

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

We have a below query which takes approximately 6-8 secs to execute.
Total number of records : 522954

```
(SELECT 
        * 
      FROM
        tbl_insights_copy
      WHERE insightscat = 21 
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC 
      LIMIT 5) 
      UNION
      (SELECT 
        * 
      FROM
        tbl_insights_copy 
      WHERE insightscat = 22 
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC 
      LIMIT 5) 
      UNION
      (SELECT 
        * 
      FROM
        tbl_insights_copy 
      WHERE insightscat = 23 
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC 
      LIMIT 5) 
      UNION
      (SELECT 
        * 
      FROM
        tbl_insights_copy 
      WHERE insightscat = 24 
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC 
      LIMIT 5)
```

Can someone help to optimize this query as to reduce the execution time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your tbl_insights_copy  table schema

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you are changing between one select and another, is the filter value of the column `insightscat` I am not sure that this is what you want but....

You may try the `IN` instruction for this. Example:

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM
        tbl_insights_copy 
      WHERE insightscat in (20,21,22,23,24)
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC
```

Comment: then where is `LIMIT 5` for each `insightscat `

Comment: you can add the limit statement at the end of the sentence whenever you want: SELECT 
        * 
FROM
        tbl_insights_copy 
      WHERE insightscat in (20,21,22,23,24)
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
      ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT ic.* 
FROM tbl_insights_copy ic
WHERE insightscat = 21 AND
      submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
ORDER BY submitedon DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

You want an index on `tbl_insights_copy(insightscat, submittedon)`.

This should work for all the subqueries.  This is probably the best approach with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t1.*
   FROM (SELECT t.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY insightscat) AS Row
       FROM 
       (select * from        
        tbl_insights_copy 
         WHERE insightscat in (20,21,22,23,24)
        AND submitedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
        ORDER BY submitedon DESC ) as t ) t1
   WHERE Row <= 5
```

Comment: `OVER` syntax is not yet available in MySQL.  It is available in MariaDB 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I am going to have to guess that you do not have the optimal

```
INDEX(insightscat, submitedon)
```

Since the `SELECTs` are distinct, use `UNION ALL` instead of the default `UNION DISTINCT`.  This will avoid an unnecessary (but fast) de-dup pass over the 20 rows.

**If you want 20 rows**

If so, my suggestions above might be best.

**If you want 6 rows**

If you want only the latest 5 from *any* of those insightscats, then there are 3 possibilities.

**Plan A**

What Developer90 says in his Comment.

**Plan B**

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY ORDER BY submitedon DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Each `SELECT` is very fast with my index.  Then, the 20 rows of the `UNION` get sorted again and `LIMIT 5` is applied.  Again, very fast.

Using the `IN` as suggested by Developer90, may or may not effectively use my index.  What version are you using?

**Plan C**

This option is hit or miss.  That is, its performance depends heavily on the distribution of the data as to whether it will be very fast or very slow:  Developer90 + `INDEX(submitedon)` (not including insightscat).